# How to deserialize json where type of properties not fixed - can be empty string or an object, please suggest. how to handle this situation?

Tags: c#, json

I have to process the JSON object returned by an API response.

I tried by creating expando object and than adding all the properties to it.
and than copying the value to it.

```
dynamic dPropertyLinkValue = new ExpandoObject();

dPropertyLinkValue.link = "";

dPropertyLinkValue.value = "";
```

I am expecting a better way to do this, without expando object.

Comment: You can parse the string to `JObject`. I don't know if that helps you as you don't know at design time what it will contain.

Comment: My json file is having around 160 properties, so I've to create a class in c# and than parse based on that template, now my problem is say one property parent sometime comes as -  "parent": "", and at times it comes like -   "parent": {
        "link": "https://dev65349.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global",
        "value": "global"
      }

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you mean by "fixed". If you know all the properties that *might* exist you can deserialize to a custom Type and values that don't exist will be null/default. If the json might have any random items that you can't predict then that is a different issue.

Comment: not fixed means if the value is not there is coming as empty string, but if value is there it comes like object, read by above comment i have given example

Comment: I did read it. Just create a type with a `parent` property that has `link` and `value` properties. Json deserialization will use `defaut()` for items not found in json. You don't need to complicate it with dynamic and expando.

Comment: Yes, earlier I was using javascriptserailzer which was provided by .net, due to which I ran into issues, after that I tried it with JsonConvert.DeserailzeObject() it works properly, but now i have to ignore null value while posting to api, for which i used cutsom serializer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deserialize JSON by casting it to dynamic object. Please refer below sample:
Here deserializing Json to **dynamic** object and after that loop through its properties and in that you can check you value that whether it is object or not.

```
        string jsonText = "{a:'testString',b:{'prop1':'value1'}}";
        var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonText);            
        foreach (JProperty property in jObj)
        {
            string text = property.Name + " : " + property.Value;
            //Here you can check whether property.Value is Jobject or any other value
        }
```